# How to Call BroadcastReceiver from Activity via Interface in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I need to set Listener for Activity Class from BroadcastReceiver Class But here in my below code I am getting null pointer exception in BroadcastReceiver class..

Here is my code

**Activity Class**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TheListener
    {
            Message_Incomingsms jv_class_Message_Incomingsms;
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                jv_class_Message_Incomingsms = new Message_Incomingsms();
                jv_class_Message_Incomingsms.setSmsReceivedistener(this);
                }

    @Override
    public void onSmsReceived(String jv_string_address, String jv_string_MessageText)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This Message is from Lister number is "+jv_string_address +" Message is "+jv_string_MessageText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Doing some Activity.....

        }

    }
```

**Interface**

```
    public void setSmsReceivedistener(Context context)
    {
        this.jv_TheListener = (TheListener)context;
    }
```

**BroadCastReceiver Class**

```
    public class Message_Incomingsms extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        String jv_string_phone_received_Number;
        String jv_string_phone_received_messageText;
        public TheListener jv_TheListener;


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.d("Received","OnReceive method is called");
            jv_smsmanager_incoming_sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            jv_bundle_incoming_sms = intent.getExtras();
            if(jv_bundle_incoming_sms!=null)
            {
                Object[] jv_pdusObj_incoming_sms = (Object[]) jv_bundle_incoming_sms.get("pdus");

                for(int jv_i = 0; jv_i < jv_pdusObj_incoming_sms.length ;jv_i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage jv_current_message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) jv_pdusObj_incoming_sms[jv_i]);
                    jv_string_phone_received_Number =jv_current_message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    jv_string_phone_received_messageText = jv_current_message.getDisplayMessageBody();

                }

            //Here Below line is problem for me Always am getting null value for  (jv_TheListener) 
            //Why value is not getting assigned for this (jv_TheListener) always
            jv_TheListener.onSmsReceived(jv_string_phone_received_Number,jv_string_phone_received_messageText);

            }
        }

            public void setSmsReceivedistener(Context context)
            {
                this.jv_TheListener = (TheListener)context;
            }
        }
```

Please provide me solution for above BroadCastClass code where am always getting null exception for **(jv_TheListener)**

**log Cat** ( I removed some lines for in code for not to confuse.. so dont refer linenumber based on below error)

```
        04-18 23:45:12.268    4064-4064/com.talkeasy.elavarasans.creativeactionbar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.talkeasy.elavarasans.creativeactionbar.Message_Incomingsms: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.talkeasy.elavarasans.creativeactionbar.Message_Incomingsms.onReceive(Message_Incomingsms.java:53)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2146)
```

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: can u plz post logact? and line on which it is crashing

Comment: Thanks for ur responce ...my problem is in BroadCastReceiver Class am always getting null for interface variable jv_TheListener to be more specific error is  on this line `jv_TheListener.onSmsReceived(jv_string_phone_received_Number,jv_string_phone_received_messageText);`

Comment: `jv_class_Message_Incomingsms ` you are setting listener throw object. But when the BroadCastReceiver triggers it always get null value (same as for all your class variable) for  `jv_TheListener`. look like you need to find another way.

Comment: Please suggest me if you have any idea to achieve this...

Comment: in receiver class`public static TheListener jv_TheListener; ` then activity class `Message_Incomingsms.jv_TheListener = //instantiation follows` another way is to use localBroacast receiver

Comment: Hey Elltz you are awesome and genius... Its worked for me ..thank you so much. Please mention this is in answer, i will mark it as correct answer so that for others will be useful if someone searching like me